# How to check whether user is authenticated or not in getServerSideProps [NodeJS - Backend]?

Tags: node.js, next.js, getserversideprops

I'm using NextJS for my frontend and NodeJS(Express) for the back. I tried using the `getServerSideProps` to check and pre-render whether user is authenticated or not but it doesn't work. I tried adding `credentials: 'include'` but it didn't work either

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });

  if (response.status === 401) {
    return {
      props: { data: null },
    };
  }
  const result = await response.json();
  return {
    props: {
      data: result,
    },
  };
}
```

Error:

- url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user',
- status: 401,
- statusText: 'Unauthorized',
- headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
- counter: 0

I know client-side using the `useEffect()` might do the trick but I don't want to see the state change once it's done rendering.

For example: in my navbar, if the user is authenticated it should display the `username`, if not then just 'login'. But every time I refresh it will display 'login' first then after a few seconds it will change into `username` (assuming the user was logged in).

Is there any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your `/api/auth/user` endpoint look like?

Comment: @juliomalves NodeJS App: `router.get('/auth/user', middleware.isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {   res.status(200).json(req.user); })`

Comment: Need to provide more details, what's in `middleware.isAuthenticated`? Please add the code to your question.

Comment: @juliomalves  `exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.user) {
    return res.status(401).send('You must login first!');
  }
  next();
};`

It's just a checker whether or not a user is authenticated

Comment: Exactly, which means that check is not passing, as it's returning a `401` response. Where does `req.user` come from?